# Retrieving an RDN from an Active Directory User Object

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to retrieve the RDN of a user object in Active Directory with the attribute intact.

I've done a lot of reading on this and found that an AD user object stores the RDN in an property called "name".  Supposedly the value of the name (rdn) property should be something like name = "cn=Smith, Joe".  The cn attribute is part of what should be returned.  However whenever I retrieve the name property of an object the "cn=" always seems to be missing.  For instance

```
$foo = get-aduser -filter 'Name -like "Smith, Joe"'
```

`$foo.name`

will return `"Smith, Joe"` not `"cn=Smith, Joe"`.  Is there someway to query and get the full RDN to return?

Comment: Any reason `"CN=${foo.name}"` doesn't meet your needs? The RDN for user objects will always start with `CN=`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, is to grab the full DN of the object, split the DN, and display the first element in the resulting array, which will be the RDN, either CN= or otherwise, object dependent

```
$((foo.distinguishedname).split(","))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but informations :

**First the attributeId of the RDN attribute is fixed by the schema :**
On the RDN point of view Active-Directory inherit from X500 standard. That is to say that you don't choose the attribute you want to create the RDN (in other LDAP directories you can). In Active-Directory the RDN attribute is given in the class schema by [rDNAttID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220795%28v=prot.10%29.aspx), it specifies the attributeId of the RDN attribute. If you look the schema for the class `user` it's `CN`.

So you can use :

```
"CN=$((get-aduser 'Smith, Joe').Name)"
```

**Second do the following experiment :**
In an OU create a user called 'Mananegement' you have the following DN `CN=MAnagement,OU=MyOU,...` now try to create, in the same OU, an OU named 'Mananegement' it should create an object with the following DN `OU=MAnagement,OU=MyOU,...`, but you receive an error. This error makes me beleive that somehow Active-Directory consider 'Mananegement' as the RDN and not 'CN=Mananegement' like others directories.

Answer (score 0):

$current.Substring($current.IndexOf('OU='))